# running wp-cron.php using php not wget

Tags: php, admin, wp-cron, cron

I operate some servers which have a few WordPress websites on them. I was having some issues with the cron jobs being triggered too often or not enough so I replaced all of them with crontab entries, one or more for each site as appropriate.

Most documentation I have seen uses `curl` or `wget` and dumps the output to `/dev/null` so I wanted to use PHP directly since it is a PHP file after all and I would then capture any error output that way.

This accomplishes the tasks I want to fine however now every few weeks I get several of the following messages:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address:  (setFrom) wordpress@' in /path/to/website/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:1023
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/website/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('wordpress@', 'WordPress', false)
#1 /path/to/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php(769): wp_mail('<adminemail>', '<subject>', '<message>', '')
#2 /path/to/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php(501): WP_Automatic_Updater->send_email('success', Object(stdClass))
#3 /path/to/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php(470): WP_Automatic_Updater->after_core_update(Object(stdClass))
#4 /path/to/website/public_html/wp-includes/update.php(532): WP_Automatic_Updater->run()
#5 [internal function]: wp_maybe_auto_update( in /path/to/website/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 1023
```

As I understand it, `wp-cron.php` has successfully caused the WordPress to be updated to the next version and wanted to email the site administrator about it.

Examining the code of `wp-includes/pluggable.php` I can see that it tries to generate a "from email address" using the contents of `$_SERVER` which obviously aren't there as it is being run from the command line and not via the web server.

I feel that using PHP directly from the command line is more efficient than invoking `curl` or `wget` but also there is no error checking present to verify a "from email address" has been generated correctly.

My question is, which of the following is true (or are both?) and what should I do about it:

1) `wp-cron.php` should ONLY be called using `wget` or `curl` and there is error checking missing that would force the administrator to avoid cli

2) `wp-includes/pluggable.php` is missing email validation checking

I can see there has been hefty debate about how an email address should be generated but am keen to not dig up resolved arguments and would appreciate a direction in resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you ok with hooking into `apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from', $from_email );` and within the filter callback set your from email address?

Comment: That would be a good solution, the websites have custom themes so adding more code wouldn't be an issue. My question is more about something being missing within WordPress itself though as one would hope the code would be more resilient.

Comment: Have you tried using WP CLI to run the cron? Your email issue seems unrelated to how cron is triggered